# Hibernate date operations

Tags: java, database, hibernate, db2, hql

I use hibernate with DB2 and have the following problem. The table/entity `Customer` has the fields `first_name`, `last_name`, `birthday`(`java.util.Date`). I need do write a query which will retrieve all customers which have birthday in the next four days. The problem is that for some customers the year of birth is unknown so it was set to 9999 in database, and therefor I can not just do a simple check in the where clause (because of the year 9999).

Comment: How would 9999 translate to a date?

Comment: For unknown values it is usually better to go with NULL, instead of dummies. Also, are you quering the db with HQL or Criteria API?

Comment: @Vikdor: There are two cases. The first is that the full date is known and so saved to db. The other cases is when only the day and month of birth are known. For example a customer was born on 10.12 so it will be saved as 10.12.9999 to the db and I am not allowed to change this logic.

Comment: @vstoyanov I would like to use HQL, but it would be also ok to use the Criteria API.

Comment: @alicica87 I have modified the query to comply DB2 SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using the simple hql query

```
from Customer as user where month(user.birthday) = month(current_date()+4 days) and day(user.birthday) = day(current_date()+4 days)
union all
from Customer as user where month(user.birthday) = month(current_date()+3 days) and day(user.birthday) = day(current_date()+3 days)
union all
from Customer as user where month(user.birthday) = month(current_date()+2 days) and day(user.birthday) = day(current_date()+2 days)
union all
from Customer as user where month(user.birthday) = month(current_date()+1 day) and day(user.birthday) = day(current_date()+1 day)
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, but what will be the result of month(current_date()+4) if the current month is december?

Comment: depends on date if the date 28.12.2012 then 1.

Comment: I am not sure about DB2 sql syntax may be need to add `+4 days` or `+1 day`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So the number that you add to current_date is the number of days. Thanks for the help, and do you have maybe a link to some references about this date arithmetics.

Comment: There's a link http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.qmf.doc.ref%2Fdsqi2mst267.htm